# Always receiving .systemMedium when requesting Environment widget family

Tags: ios, swift, widgetkit

I'm trying to get the right widget family in a view, but I'm always getting **.systemMedium** value. This is my view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyView: View
{
    @Environment(\.widgetFamily) var family

    let entry: MyEntry

    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View
    {
        switch family
        {
        case .systemSmall:
           Text("systemSmall")
        case .systemMedium:
           Text("systemMedium")
        case .systemLarge:
           Text("systemLarge")
        case .systemExtraLarge:
           Text("systemExtraLarge")
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: did you set up the config? 


`var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            MyViewEntry(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("Name")
        .description("Descr")
        .supportedFamilies([.systemSmall, .systemMedium, .systemLarge])
    }`

In particular: `.supportedFamilies([.systemSmall, .systemMedium, .systemLarge])`

Comment: Yes, I did it this way.

Comment: Same problem here. This used to work with Xcode 12.

Comment: Looks like a bug in SwiftUI Previews. I have filed feedback regarding this. FB9950816. You should feedback as well! It works fine when ran on Simulator or real device.

Comment: I've litteratly just written the same code :) -- its still an issue in xcode 13.2.1 (I'm still on Big Sur)

Comment: Bug still present in 13.3.1

Answer (score 1):

#### Cautionary tale, **do NOT copy** the below code blindly!

For me, at first this was happening for the previews in Xcode, so I searched around and implemented these extensions:

```
// DEBUG
extension WidgetFamily: EnvironmentKey {
    public static var defaultValue: WidgetFamily = .systemSmall
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
  var widgetFamily: WidgetFamily {
    get { self[WidgetFamily.self] }
    set { self[WidgetFamily.self] = newValue }
  }
}
```

as well as specifying the family environment directly for the previews:

```
Group {
   SWidgetEntryView(entry: SimpleEntry(date: Date()))
     .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemSmall))
     .environment(\.widgetFamily, .systemSmall)
   SWidgetEntryView(entry: SimpleEntry(date: Date()))
     .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemMedium))
     .environment(\.widgetFamily, .systemMedium)
}
```

This will solve the issue during preview, but **will mess up the widgets on the device**, as it overrides the `widgetFamily` environment variable. All widget sizes will have the incorrect family environment that you specify for `defaultValue`.

If this kind of problem is happening for you on the device, you probably implemented a similar extension to make previews work. Removing it will fix the issue on the device. I'm not sure what's the correct fix for the previews.

Comment: Damn you're right! Thanks so much